# php regex match only none http://, https://

Tags: php, regex

I've question about how can I match only none `http://,https://`.

This is my regex now it select all link and replace with my full url.

But problem is when my `$string` got the right url but the replace function alway replace it with `http://example.comhttp://google.com/test`

```
$string = 'test <a href="/web/data.html">link1</a> <a href="http://google.com/test">link2</a>';

$pattern = "/<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU";

$response = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($matches) {
    return '<a href="http://example.com'.$matches[2].'">'.$matches[3].'</a>';
},  $string);
var_dump($response);
```

the result now is:

```
test <a href="http://example.com/web/data.html">link1</a> <a href="http://example.comhttp://google.com/test">link2</a>
```

the expect result is:

```
test <a href="http://example.com/web/data.html">link1</a> <a href="http://google.com/test">link2</a>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simpler approach with a regex like this:

```
href="/
```

And replacement string:

```
href="http://example.com/
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/uT7iO5/1)**

Php code

```
$re = '~href="/~'; 
$str = "test <a href=\"/web/data.html\">link1</a> <a href=\"http://google.com/test\">link2</a>\n\n"; 
$subst = "href=\"http://example.com/"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

// output
test <a href="http://example.com/web/data.html">link1</a> <a href="http://google.com/test">link2</a>
```